# Access const inside async function in react-native / expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to use the [expo-av lib](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/sdk/av/)

I use the following async function to play a sound file from an URL:

```
PlaySound = async (soundURL) => {
    try { 
        const playbackObject = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            { uri: soundURL },
            { shouldPlay: this.state.shouldPlay }
        );
     } catch (error) {
           console.log('ERROR:'+error);
           // Error retrieving data
     }

    return playbackObject;
};


stopSound = async (soundURL) => {
try {

  this.setState({shouldPlay:false});
   const playbackObject = await PlaySound(soundURL);

 } catch (error) {
  console.log('ERROR:'+error);
  // Error retrieving data
}
playbackObject.stopAsync(); // this is causing the error
};
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:ReferenceError: Can't find variable: playbackObject
>
> [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   playbackObject]

The `PlaySound` functions works as I want. Now I want to be able to pause/stop using the `stopSound` function. [The documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/) says to use `soundObject.stopAsync()` which in my case would be `playbackObject`. But I can't figure out how to access this const outside of the function?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Return it from the async function and then await the returned promise. It will resolve to the playbackObject.

Comment: @Li357 thanks for the reply - Can you show me how to return it and then use it outside of the function?

Comment: `return playbackObject` in the try block, then call `const playbackObject = await PlaySound(…)` where you need the object. Be sure to handle the catch block.

Comment: @Li357 thanks for the reply - I have updated my question, since I still cant get it to work :(

Comment: That's a class property. It should be `this.PlaySound`

Comment: Also, `playbackObject` is only in scope inside the try block. Regular JS rules still apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference a const that was defined inside of a try/catch outside of the try catch. You can fix this by doing either of the following:

```
let playbackObject;

try { 
  playbackObject = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
    { uri: soundURL },
    { shouldPlay: this.state.shouldPlay }
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log('ERROR:'+error);
  // Error retrieving data
}

return playbackObject;
```

or

```
try { 
  return Audio.Sound.createAsync(
    { uri: soundURL },
    { shouldPlay: this.state.shouldPlay }
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log('ERROR:'+error);
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

In order to fix the stop function, you should maintain a reference to the playbackObject that is returned by the start function and use that in the stop function, since the way you currently have it would create a new audio stream that you would then stop (leaving the original in tact).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. Im very new to async functions and cant wrap my head around how I get to use the .stopAsync(); - you answer works, but could you show me how to assign this value returned value to a new variable and apply newVariable.stopAsync(); ? Im basicly trying to build a play/pause button, but this has kept me on hold all day

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I read your question wrong in the first place, I've added an edit, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, This helped me a lot. I found that I also had to restructure my code, since the promise was never ready when running the functions. This worked better when using the object after the inside the render() function in react-native.